# Android Server Socket Chat App Java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

It is single activity app, user is given 2 options "server" or "client" if user selects server then screen gives 2 fields port and username and then when clicked connect it waits on that screen until a client connects then it moves to chat screen.

I am creating a client server socket chat app in android. Below is my connect button code. When I run the app it gives Java.net.BindException

function is passed viewModel and navHostController, onStatusChanged changes text on button.

```
        fun onConnectClicked(
            viewModel: AppViewModel,
            navHostController: NavHostController
        ) {
            if (_ip.value.isNullOrBlank()) {
                // Server
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    try {
                        server = ServerSocket(port.value!!.toInt())
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                            viewModel.onStatusChanged("The Server is accepting requests")
                        }
                        socket = server!!.accept()
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                            viewModel.onStatusChanged("Connection Established with $socket")
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.i("tag", e.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // Client
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    try {
                        socket = Socket(ip.value.toString() ,port.value!!.toInt())
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                            viewModel.onStatusChanged("Sending request to Server...")
                        }
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch{
                            viewModel.onStatusChanged("Connection Established with Server")
                        }
                    }
                    catch (e: BindException) {
                        Log.i("tag",e.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
//        bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket!!.getInputStream()))
//        printWriter = PrintWriter(socket!!.getOutputStream())

            navHostController.navigate(Screen.Chat.route)
        }
```

I am think error is in the coroutine part.

Comment: The exception means there is already a server running on that port in your machine. For example, if you have an Apache server running on port 80 and you try to start a server on port 80, you will get that exception. It could be that you are not closing the serversocket and restarting the application and the old server will still be running.

Comment: Logs or error description can be helpful here